# LXML/Elementree correctly returns tag attribute value from first rss feed, generates 'Nonetype has no attribute get' error in second

Tags: python-2.7, xml-parsing, lxml, elementtree

I'm trying to write an app in Python 2.7 to use on Google App Engine. I want it to parse rss feeds and store the data in a database, but I get inconsistent behavior when getting the value of the 'url' attribute in the 'enclosure' tag. I'm new to coding and would appreciate any help on this.

I have two rss feeds:

Feed A: http://youhadtobethere.libsyn.com/rss

```
<item>
<title>Episode 97: Yannis Pappas</title>
<pubDate>Thu, 07 Feb 2013 19:38:00 +0000</pubDate>
<guid isPermaLink="false"><![CDATA[1364808bb99fe6bdb71b16333530076f]]></guid>
<link><![CDATA[http://youhadtobethere.libsyn.com/episode-97-yannis-pappas]]></link>
<media:thumbnail url="http://assets.libsyn.com/item/2210463" />
<description><![CDATA[<div>This week, Nikki and Sara marvel at how, two weeks in, they've already gotten used to the process of making their television show.&nbsp; Sara recently saw <i>Django Unchained</i> in a now-rare moment of free time and when she says she liked it, Brooklyn-born comic and certified "grown man" (see <a href="http://splitsider.com/2013/02/you-had-to-be-there-96-jessimae-peluso/">ep. 96</a>) <a href="http://ditchfilms.com/?page_id=2">Yannis Pappas</a> (<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PWSRHNvTSIU"><i>Modern Comedian</i></a>, <a href="https://twitter.com/yannispappas">Twitter</a>) offers his wholehearted agreement.&nbsp; After flinging fury at Brooklyn's bogus new neighborhoods, Philly's sports obsessions, and Beantown's general demeanor, Yannis tells the story of the shooting that shoved him into maturity early on in his career.&nbsp; The trio muse a bit on their futile little legacies but soon leap into a joyous edition of Talking Pee that includes a <a href="http://whatsongamidancingto.com/">previral guessing game</a> on YouTube, a <a href="http://www.fitbit.com/">playful pedometer</a> on everyone's waistband, Yannis's modest dog zoo, and Nikki's upcoming appearance on <a href="http://www.comedycentral.com/shows/the-burn-with-jeff-ross"><i>The Burn</i></a>.&nbsp; Check her out this Tuesday (2/12) on Comedy Central at 10.30pm/9.30c...<br /><br /></div>
<p>...conveniently right before you flip over to <b><i>Nikki &amp; Sara LIVE</i></b> on <b>MTV </b>at <b>11pm/10c</b>.&nbsp; <i>Nikki &amp; Sara LIVE</i>: like a podcast for your eyes!</p>]]></description>
<enclosure length="61227675" type="audio/mpeg" url="http://traffic.libsyn.com/youhadtobethere/YHTBT_97_YannisPappas.mp3" />
<itunes:duration>01:03:47</itunes:duration>
<itunes:explicit>no</itunes:explicit>
<itunes:keywords>pappas,sara,nikki,schaefer,glaser,yannis</itunes:keywords>
<itunes:subtitle><![CDATA[This week, Nikki and Sara marvel at how, two weeks in, they've already gotten used to the process of making their television show.&nbsp; Sara recently saw Django Unchained in a now-rare moment of free time and when she says she liked it, Brooklyn-born...]]></itunes:subtitle>
</item>
```

Feed B: http://smodcast.com/channels/bagged-boarded-live/feed/

```
<item>
<title>
Bagged & Boarded Live 146: All Superheroes Must Pod
</title>
<link>
http://smodcast.com/episodes/all-superheroes-must-pod/
</link>
<comments>
http://smodcast.com/episodes/all-superheroes-must-pod/#comments
</comments>
<pubDate>Tue, 22 Jan 2013 00:08:35 +0000</pubDate>
<dc:creator>Editor</dc:creator>
<category>
<![CDATA[ Episodes ]]>
</category>
<guid isPermaLink="false">http://smodcast.com/?p=12999</guid>
<description>
<![CDATA[
In which Matt sits down with Jason Trost (The Fp) and Lucas Till (X-Men First Class) for a chat about their new film All Superheroes Must Die
]]>
</description>
<content:encoded>
<![CDATA[
In which Matt sits down with Jason Trost (The Fp) and Lucas Till (X-Men First Class) for a chat about their new film All Superheroes Must Die
]]>
</content:encoded>
<wfw:commentRss>
http://smodcast.com/episodes/all-superheroes-must-pod/feed/
</wfw:commentRss>
<slash:comments>0</slash:comments>
<enclosure url="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/75907996/stream.mp3?client_id=a427c512429c9c90e58de7955257879c" length="0" type="audio/mpeg"/>
</item>
```

The code snippet:

```
import urllib

from lxml import etree

rss = etree.parse(urllib.urlopen(feedUrl))
show = rss.getroot()

for episode in show.iter('item'):
    mediaUrl = episode.xpath('enclosure/@url')
```

This returns a list with the value of the url attribute as the only item. When run on Feed A, I can use mediaUrl = episode.xpath('enclosure/@url')[0] instead, or mediaUrl = mediaUrl[0] to save that url as a string. On Feed B, however, both of those generate the error: IndexError: list index out of range. If I use len(mediaUrl) on the list returned from Feed B I get a result of 1, which I take to mean that it has returned a list with the url in it, but trying to get the url out of that list generates the IndexError.

I've tried:

```
enclosure = episode.find('enclosure') 
mediaUrl = enclosure.get('url')
```

And this gets the url as a string just fine from Feed A, but generates an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' error in Feed B. I get the same behavior when I use:

```
mediaUrl = episode.find('enclosure').attrib['url']
```

Correctly returns the url as a string from Feed A, generates AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrib' from Feed B.

I don't see an obvious difference between the layout of the two rss feeds to explain why the url can easily be plucked from Feed A using the last two methods, but not seen at all in Feed B. And I don't understand why I can extract the url from the list returned from Feed A using the first method, but not from the list returned from Feed B. Can anyone help?

Comment: Any reason you are not using the [`feedparser` library](http://code.google.com/p/feedparser/)?

Comment: I'll definitely take a look at feedparser. Element tree seemed to be getting the job done, so I didn't really look at alternate solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is assuming that *all* items in the feed will have an `<enclosure />` tag.

For your first feed, that is indeed the case, but at the time of this post, the second feed URL has *two* items that do *not* have a enclosure URL included.

Simply skip these items:

```
for episode in show.iter('item'):
    mediaUrl = episode.xpath('enclosure/@url')
    if not mediaUrl:  # no enclosure for this episode
        continue
```